# Almost as though "else if statement" is giving me 2 ReadLines() If the user types the second or third options

Tags: c#, if-statement, double, readline

Why is it that every time I have a second `if/else if` statement, I have to enter whatever the second `if` condition is, twice? Almost as though its giving me 2 ReadLines() for some reason

```
//Directions (Actions) You May Take:

    public string forward = "forward";
    public string back    = "back";
    public string left    = "left";
    public string right   = "right";


    public void closet()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("You open the door at the top of the basement staircase and it leads to what appears to be a closet?");
        Console.WriteLine("You can feel random clutter but it's still so dark. There is another door in front of you...");
        Console.WriteLine("Only 2 directions you can take. [BACK] or [FORWARD]");
        if (forward == Console.ReadLine())
        {
            hallway();
        }
        if (back == Console.ReadLine())
        {
            Console.WriteLine("The door behind you to the basement is now locked... weird...");
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine(wrong);
        }
    }

    public void hallway()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("\nYou open the door in front of you and crawl out into what appears to be a hallway.");
        Console.WriteLine("There are 3 direcitons you can take. [BACK] or [LEFT] or [RIGHT]");
        Console.WriteLine("What direction do you take?");
        if (left == Console.ReadLine())
        {
            bathroom();
        }

        if (right == Console.ReadLine())
        {
           livingroom();
        }
        else
        {
           Console.WriteLine(wrong);
        }

    }

    public void bathroom()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("This is the bathroom");
    }

    public void livingroom()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("This is the livingroom");
    }
```

Comment: I read your question a couple of times. but couldn't find what you're asking about

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are pulling from the console multiple times.  You want to only pull once.
Something like this instead:

```
var direction = Console.ReadLine()
if (left == direction)
{
    bathroom();
}

if (right == direction)
{
   livingroom();
}
else
{
   Console.WriteLine(wrong);
}
```

Comment: Thanks! That really cleared it up!

Comment: @user3080463 thanks!  Perhaps you've figured it out by now, but once you readline from the console, there is no going back.  The console releases the thread and work continues.  Thats why reading multiple times wasnt giving you the result you wanted.

Answer (score 4):

Because you call `Console.ReadLine()` twice and each time it takes input. You only compare the second time against the second condition. You want:

```
var inputString = Console.ReadLine();
if (inputString == forward)
{
    hallway();
}
else if (inputString == back)
{
    Console.WriteLine("The door behind you to the basement is now locked... weird...");
}
```

You'll need to do this for both sets of conditionals.

Comment: thanks so much for your time to answer that question! It helped! I'm just finishing my first programming class so I'm super new.

Comment: Great answer +1.  Its amazing what 30 seconds can make for upvotes :)

Answer (score 0):

That is because you have two Console.ReadLine-calls. You need to move a single ReadLine call in front of the if-statements and evaluate the if-conditions against the result.